# How to properly deploy and use fabcar example chaincode written in node.js to AWS managed blockchain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

I followed the steps from [Steps to deploy AWS NGO chaincode](https://github.com/aws-samples/non-profit-blockchain/blob/master/ngo-chaincode/README.md)
and instead of NGO chaincode I tried [fabcar node.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/fabcar/javascript/lib/fabcar.js) chaincode from fabric samples. But I'm facing error during instantiation. I saw that the basic format of chaincodes are different but will that really cause any hindrance in the flow ?

I want to know if this will work and if not how can I use fabcar javascript chaincode on AWS blockchain.

This is the error I'm facing while instantiation
[image: Error]

Please guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a documentation (step by step) to setup the Blockchain network and deploy the chaincode using the AWS Managed Blockchain.

https://github.com/sjais789/AWS_Managed_Bockchain_Setup

If you are stuck somewhere feel free to comment it here.

Comment: Yes, I've followed the same steps but they do not work for this https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/chaincode/fabcar/javascript/lib/fabcar.js

Comment: Can you please share the error logs when you deploy the fabcar chaincode.

Answer (score 1):

The fabcar example has fabric-contract-api. The peers in amazon managed blockchain neither have that dependency pre-installed nor it has internet connection to download the dependency. This is a huge problem. They've suggested to bundle the dependencies before instantiating it but haven't shown any way to do that.

However, there is a way out of this. Instead of using the usual fabcar example for javascript, if you use fabcar javascript-low-level chaincode, that does not make use of the fabric-contract-api, then you'll be able to use the chaincode in aws managed blockchain.